# GETDATE -1 or 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, getdate

With this:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(month,1,GETDATE()),120)
```

I get this

```
2013-08-19
```

which is perfect but I need it to output one or two days less

example: `2013-08-18`

Any tips?

Comment: did you try using `-1` or `-2` with your `getdate()`?  Did you try another `dateadd`?

Comment: When would you subtract one day, and when would you subtract two?

Comment: OP I don't understand how you could possibly ask this question. You are already using the DATEADD function! You know DATEADD exists and are using it to add a month. Just subtract a day as well.

Answer (score 7):

For 1 day less you could use

```
Select CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120)
```

or for 2 days difference use

```
Select CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())),120)
```

The convert will make it the format you seek and the dateadd  will change the dd or day with -1 or 2 whichever you are wanting to use at that time.

Answer (score 2):

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())-1,120)

select CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())-2,120)
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer by @traxs above?

Answer (score 1):

if you subtract the results of dateadd by 1 or 2 you should get the desired output.

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(month,1,GETDATE())-1,120)
```

or

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(month,1,GETDATE())-2,120)
```

Comment: Be careful about implicit dateadd. This math works for adding/subtracting days from a datetime or smalldatetime, but it falls over miserably if you later change to newer types like date, datetime2, datetimeoffset...